# How to save VIM filetype settings for a file which is being mis-detected?

Tags: vim, apache-http-server, filetype

The Apache config file for my website is named `mywebsite.com`. Apparently the extension `.com` is causing vim to set the wrong file type as `dcl` which makes the syntax highlighting wrong as well. All of my other host config files are correctly identified as Apache files.

I am able to `:set filetype=apache` and everything looks great but when after closing vim and coming back to edit the file type is back to `dcl` again.

Other than renaming my host config file, is there a solution to this? Is there a way to make vim remember the filetype of this one particular file? Or better yet, is there a way to correct this wrong file type detection?

Comment: *Never* do anything in `/usr/share/vim/`: all your custom stuff must sit in your `~/.vimrc` file and your `~/.vim/` directory.

Comment: 1. Everything under `/usr/share/vim/` is susceptible to be replaced during the next upgrade; do you want your changes to disappear with no way to get them back? 2. The purpose of that dir is to provide a baseline environment; tinkering with it affects Vim's stability and behavior in unpredictable ways. Your change is probably innocuous but any future change may not be. 3. You have a special place under your control where you can do whatever you want to alter Vim's behavior safely and without needing admin rights, use it. 4. `~` is where you traditionally do all your configuration; use it.

Comment: thank you.  that's some sound reasoning and i'll take your advice on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to add a *modeline* to the beginning or end of the file. A basic [Vim modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) looks like this:

```
# vim: ft=apache
```

The comment character itself is ignored by Vim. There is also an alternative syntax that allows following comment characters as well:

```
/* vim: set ft=apache: */
```

Emacs and some other editors use `-*- mode: apache -*-` instead.

---

If you wanted to override the file type detection by extension, you could add the following to your `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.com setl ft=apache
augroup END
```

(I am not sure if `setf apache` or `setl ft=apache` is better.)

---

Note that the detection isn't entirely wrong, it's merely inaccurate. The OpenVMS operating system uses `.com` as the extension for "command" files – much like shell scripts or batch files – and they're written in the OpenVMS shell language, DCL ([DIGITAL Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGITAL_Command_Language)).

Comment: Thanks very much!  I didn't know about modelines.  And yes, I vaguely remember that .com extension from scripting DCL on VMS in the 80's.

Answer (score 5):

How to do this is described in Vim's built-in reference manual under

```
:help new-filetype
```

As explained in section C.2., create a file named `~/.vim/filetype.vim` with these contents:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
    finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.com setfiletype apache
augroup END
```

That will recognize any file ending in `.com` as filetype apache. If you want only `mywebsite.com` to be recognized, change that `au` line to

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile mywebsite.com setfiletype apache
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to both the below answers I'd like to share what I did in the end which is to modify the main config file /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim from:

> au BufNewFile,BufRead *.com         call s:BindzoneCheck('dcl')

to

> au BufNewFile,BufRead *.com         call s:BindzoneCheck('apache')

I realize this may not be appropriate for every user, particularly if you ever intend to write dcl scripts, but in my case this is fine.

*Note: I migrated this from an edit on my question to a proper answer. At the time I wrote it I didn't have enough rep to add an answer, but now I do. User @romainl brought up some valid reasons* ***not*** *to do it this way in the comment on my question above, but at the very least I think this is useful because it helps shed light on where those filetype associations are originate.*